# sql fetching time slower speed up the query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT 
SA.YEAR,            
sum(SA.QUANTITY1),                          
sum(SA.QUANTITY2),          
sum(SA.QUANTITY3),   
sum(SA.QUANTITY4),  
sum(CD.QUANTITY5),   
sum(CD.QUANTITY6),
sum(CD.QUANTITY7),  
sum(CD.QUANTITY8)

FROM SIEM_DETAILS SA, REAP_DETAILS CD

GROUP BY SA.YEAR;
```

I have an sql query where it displays sum of the QUANTITYs which were grouped by the year.
The issue is it takes up around 25 minutes to fetch the rows.

Those tables contain around 20,000 records.

I  tried to create an index on each of the column but it did not work.

How can I speed up the query where it can fetch the records and display the sum in a very short amount of time???

Below is a sample SQL Fiddle

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e220908a49c0dc8ac61388aa1b241ea4

Tried this way too

```
FROM SIEM_DETAILS SA
JOIN REAP_DETAILS CD
ON CD.ENTRY_ID = SA.ENTRY_ID

GROUP BY SA.YEAR;
```

But the time to display result is slow

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Can you show us an execution plan for the query?

Comment: 20.000 rows is *puny* for Oracle, so I suspect that Oracle is a *victim* here, not a *culprit*. What does the DBA say? Is server OK?

Comment: First of all, the query without the join condition is almost certainly wrong.  If both tables have 20,000 rows, that first query you posted is processing a 400 million row Cartesian product.  So, mystery probably solved.  In the query with the join condition: is `ENTRY_ID` a unique key in at least ONE of those two tables?  Otherwise, you could be encountering a "fan trap" and still processing a lot of records during your query (AND getting incorrect results too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it contain a join condition there? Like:

```sql
SELECT 
SA.YEAR,            
sum(SA.QUANTITY1),                          
sum(SA.QUANTITY2),          
sum(SA.QUANTITY3),   
sum(SA.QUANTITY4),  
sum(CD.QUANTITY5),   
sum(CD.QUANTITY6),
sum(CD.QUANTITY7),  
sum(CD.QUANTITY8)

FROM SIEM_DETAILS SA, REAP_DETAILS CD
WHERE sa.ENTRY_ID=cd.ENTRY_ID
GROUP BY SA.YEAR;
```

Update: There is also another approach: to use manual group-by-placement transformation:

```sql
SELECT 
   SA.YEAR,            
   sum(SA.QUANTITY1),                          
   sum(SA.QUANTITY2),          
   sum(SA.QUANTITY3),   
   sum(SA.QUANTITY4),  
   sum(CD.QUANTITY5),   
   sum(CD.QUANTITY6),
   sum(CD.QUANTITY7),  
   sum(CD.QUANTITY8)
FROM 
(
   select 
      YEAR,
      ENTRY_ID,
      sum(QUANTITY1) QUANTITY1,                          
      sum(QUANTITY2) QUANTITY2,          
      sum(QUANTITY3) QUANTITY3,   
      sum(QUANTITY4) QUANTITY4
   FROM SIEM_DETAILS
   group by YEAR,ENTRY_ID
) sa,
(
   select
      ENTRY_ID
      sum(QUANTITY5) QUANTITY5,   
      sum(QUANTITY6) QUANTITY6,
      sum(QUANTITY7) QUANTITY7,  
      sum(QUANTITY8) QUANTITY8
   from REAP_DETAILS 
   group by ENTRY_ID
) cd
WHERE sa.ENTRY_ID=cd.ENTRY_ID
GROUP BY SA.YEAR;
```

I'm not sure if your REAP_DETAILS has YEAR column. If yes, you need to add this column into `cd` inline view like:

```
SELECT 
   SA.YEAR,            
   sum(SA.QUANTITY1),                          
   sum(SA.QUANTITY2),          
   sum(SA.QUANTITY3),   
   sum(SA.QUANTITY4),  
   sum(CD.QUANTITY5),   
   sum(CD.QUANTITY6),
   sum(CD.QUANTITY7),  
   sum(CD.QUANTITY8)
FROM 
(
   select 
      YEAR,
      ENTRY_ID,
      sum(QUANTITY1) QUANTITY1,                          
      sum(QUANTITY2) QUANTITY2,          
      sum(QUANTITY3) QUANTITY3,   
      sum(QUANTITY4) QUANTITY4
   FROM SIEM_DETAILS
   group by YEAR,ENTRY_ID
) sa,
(
   select
      YEAR,ENTRY_ID
      sum(QUANTITY5) QUANTITY5,   
      sum(QUANTITY6) QUANTITY6,
      sum(QUANTITY7) QUANTITY7,  
      sum(QUANTITY8) QUANTITY8
   from REAP_DETAILS 
   group by YEAR,ENTRY_ID
) cd
WHERE sa.ENTRY_ID=cd.ENTRY_ID
GROUP BY SA.YEAR;
```

Comment: tried that way too,but the query is taking a lot of time as the tables contain 20000 records.

Comment: @aliceau "a lot of time" - how long? Could you provide real execution plan with statistics?

Comment: Create index on the column entry_id for both tables. Also, try to do gather statistics on the tables. Example of syntax below.                                                         EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats('SCOTT', 'EMPLOYEES'); — schema, tablename